# Update table2 column by table1 column value with NOT LIKE

Tags: mysql

I like to update table2 updateuser column user-number from values already present in table1 basicuser column user-num, 
table1 column user-num have more than 1000 entries multiple entries have digits like (345 or 67845 etc.) and many entries only have number 0, I want to skip lines having digit 0 and only want to copy lines having digits.

I tried multiple queries but no success.
e.g.

```
UPDATE updateuser, basicuser 
SET `user-number` = basicuser.user-num 
WHERE `basicuser`.`user-num` NOT LIKE '0'
```

This query works but fills all lines of `updateuser.user-number` with first entry (e.g. 67838) of `basicuser.user-num`

Comment: please share sample data and expected output

Comment: You haven't specified which rows of `updateuser` should be updated in the `WHERE` clause, so it updates all of them. Which rows is it supposed to update? Is there a relationship between `updateuser` and `basicuser`?

Comment: BTW, you should use `=` and `!=` when you're matching an exact string, `LIKE` is for matching patterns containing wildcards.

Comment: yes in next step these values create relation in between both tables, and there is no exact row to update, I want to paste all matching results to updateuser user-number,

Comment: SOrry I do not now how to explain my problem, I want like a loop to copy all values row by row from basicuser.user-num and paste to updateuser.user-number rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to all, I found a solution, but need all of your expert advice. is this right choice or not.

```
INSERT INTO updateuser (user_number) SELECT basicuser.user_num from basicuser 
WHERE `user_num` != '0' ORDER BY `s_no` ASC
```